# Removing Colon's From Form Element ID's in Magento

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui, magento, magento-1.4

For some absolutely ridiculous reason, Magento adds in colons to ID attributes more annoying on the checkout page of which I am trying to style using jQuery. The jQuery plugin I am using for custom selects is breaking because of these colons which look like a bad idea in the first place to me.

For example the state/province select on the checkout has an ID of "billing:region_id" which is auto-generated. Is there a way to remove these colons, or perhaps even change it to a hyphen? Using colons seems like a pretty bad idea, I wonder why that is.

The custom select dropdown plugin is the one in jQuery UI dev which can be seen [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/selectmenu).

Your help is gratefully appreciated.

Comment: since you're already using jquery [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/escape) might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Colons are completely valid characters in IDs, and jQuery supports them quite fine - if you escape them using the proper CSS and JavaScript syntax:

In CSS characters in IDs that are also can be used part of the CSS syntax are escaped with a backslash (`\`). Example:

```
#billing\:region_id {
  color: red;
}
```

In JavaScript a backslash is also a special character in strings so it also needs to be escaped - with a second backslash:

```
jQuery("#billing\\:region_id").css("color", "red");
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/76jyM/

Comment: Ah, I see, I see. Thanks for your help. It appears as though the plugin I was using wasn't escaping ID's so it was breaking it, guess the developers never took that into consideration.